# Wordpress removes base64 images in visual editor

Tags: php, wordpress, image, base64

I have a problem in wordpress where images converted to base64 will show up on the website but not in the editor.

After some testing it happens when we switch to the visual editor.

[image]

When we view the text mode the image tags appear.

[image]

Is there a fix for this? I tried to google but always end up on wordpress support issue from over 3, 4 years ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a script to generate an image, and save it in the uploads folder, for each base64 image and updated the img tag.